# login not having permission to see sql server properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a login and that login should not view the sql server properties i.e.,login should not have permission to execute command select @@version

Comment: Why do you not want users not to be able to `SELECT @@version;`?

Comment: that is requirement from customer, is it possible?

Comment: OK - why is your customer making such an  unusual request? I'm not sure if it's possible - not a Microsoft SQL Server man, but it would  possibly be beneficial to know **the reason(s)** behind the request...

Comment: I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 6):

The SQL Server manual for [`@@VERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/version-transact-sql-configuration-functions) lists no specific permission requirements for running the function. To be more accurate, it does not mention permissions at all, which by itself might not mean much. However, individual parts of the server version information can be requested using the `SERVERPROPERTY` function. Now, the manual for [`SERVERPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql#permissions) does have a section on permission requirements, where it states very clearly:

> All users can query the server properties.

I believe it is fair to assume a consistent policy on querying server-wide properties using all such functions, including `@@VERSION`. Therefore, you can safely conclude that there is no obvious built-in way to restrict access to the result of the `@@VERSION` function. You will have to roll out your own custom method of suppressing this information for a given user.